# Can't get TypeScript reference to work with Chutzpah

Tags: typescript, chutzpah

I have the following files in my project folder:

- chai.d.ts
- chai.js
- mocha.d.ts
- mocha.js
- appTest.ts
- appTest.js
- chutzpah.json

The chai and mocha files have been downloaded using bower and tsd

Here is what is in the other files:

**appTest.ts:**

```
/// <chutzpah_reference path="mocha.js" />
/// <chutzpah_reference path="chai.js" />
/// <reference path="mocha.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="chai.d.ts" />
var assert = chai.assert;

test("test test", function () {
    assert.equal(1, 3, "One equals three");
});
```

**appTest.js:** (compiled by external process)

```
var assert = chai.assert;
test("test test", function () {
    assert.equal(1, 3, "One equals three");
});
```

**chutzpah.json:**

```
{
  "Compile": {
    "Mode": "External",
    "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ]
  },
  "Tests": [
    {
      "Includes": [ "*Test.ts" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I run this command in the folder:

```
chutzpah.console appTest.ts
```

And I get the following error:

```
Chutzpah console test runner  (64-bit .NET 4.0.30319.42000)
Version 4.1.0.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Matthew Manela (http://matthewmanela.com).


Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: chai
at global code in file:///C:/***/appTest.js (line 1)

While Running:C:\***\appTest.ts

File: C:\***\appTest.ts
     0 total, 0 failed, took 0.00 seconds

Tests complete: 0
=== 0 total, 0 failed, took 1.65 seconds ===
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are hitting a breaking change that was introduced in version 4.1 with regards to how Chutzpah parses file references when using the Cutzpah.json file. As a performance imrpovement Chutzpah makes scanning references inside of your test files an optional feature and prefers you listing them explicitly in the Chutzpah.json file.

See [this page](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Breaking-change-to-nested-reference-comments-in-version-4.1) for more info.

But basically, either you need to reference the files you need in the chutzpah.json file:

```
 "References": [
    {
      "Path": "chai.js"
    }
  ]
```

or mark your test file to allow scanning references:

```
  "Tests": [
        { "Includes": [ "*Test.ts" ], "ExpandReferenceComments":  "true" }
    ]
```